# What to create? a function or template or?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

I've the following problem see the code example:

```
<xsl:if test="/Document/test/id">
  <TEST1>
     <xsl:value-of select="/Document/test/id"/>
   </TEST1>
</xsl:if>
```

I've a huge xslt script with a lot of same code. I wanted to create a function but I got all the time errors. I was asking myself if that is the right solution to solve this problem.

To make the code better maintainable I want to use something like the following.
This is not xslt syntax because I don't know how, but to give an idea what I'm looking for.

```
...
<xsl:something "TEST1", "/Document/test/id1" />
<xsl:something "TEST2", "/Document/test/id2" />
...
```

The code would be better readable and maintainable, although I don't know how to solve this :-(
Any advise is welcome...

Regards Dirk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:my="my:my" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="vDoc" select="/"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:sequence select="my:test(xs:QName('Test1'), /*/test/id1/string())"/>
     <xsl:sequence select="my:test(xs:QName('Test2'), /*/test/id2/string())"/>
     <xsl:sequence select="my:test(xs:QName('Test3'), /*/test/id3/string())"/>
     <xsl:sequence select="my:test(xs:QName('Test4'), /*/test/id4/string())"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:function name="my:test">
   <xsl:param name="pName" as="xs:QName"/>
   <xsl:param name="pToPresent" as="item()?"/>

   <xsl:if test="$pToPresent">
     <xsl:element name="{$pName}">
             <xsl:sequence select="$pToPresent"/>
     </xsl:element>
   </xsl:if>
 </xsl:function>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the following XML document:**

```
<Document>
 <test>
  <id1>Some Id1</id1>
 </test>
 <test>
  <id2>Some Id2</id2>
 </test>
 <test>
  <id4>Some Id4</id4>
 </test>
</Document>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<Test1>Some Id1</Test1>
<Test2>Some Id2</Test2>
<Test4>Some Id4</Test4>
```

**Do note**:

1. The first argument of `my:test()` is declared of type `xs:QName`, which guarantees that the value of the `name` attribute of the `xsl:element` instruction is always a valid name.
2. The second argument of `my:test()` is declared very loosely of type `item()?`, which gives us the freedom to provide any type of item (string or node or element, or ...) and that exactly what is provided would be reproduced "as is".

Comment: Hi thanks a lot for the answer. I see what went wrong in my own example. In my own example I don't get the content from the xpath expression but only the string a such. The original xml I get has namespaces. Could that be the  issue?

Comment: Hello Dimitre thanks, it's working as expected. The only thing what is happening now is that I get in my output is the following:
<Test1 xmlns="">Somde Id1</Test1> how can I get rid of the empty xmlns?

Comment: @Dirk, Please, ask a new question and provide the exact XML document you are using, so that the readers and potential repliers will not have to guess.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the closest to what you are going for:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:f="custom-functions" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <CONTENT>
      <xsl:sequence select="f:rename('TEST1', /Document/test/id1)"/>
      <xsl:sequence select="f:rename('TEST2', /Document/test/id2)"/>
    </CONTENT>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:function name="f:rename">
    <xsl:param name="name" as="xs:string"/>
    <xsl:param name="toWrap" />

    <xsl:if test="$toWrap">
      <xsl:element name="{$name}">
        <xsl:value-of select="$toWrap"/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:function>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When this is run on the following input:

```
<Document>
  <test>
    <id1>Hello!</id1>
    <id2>Hello again!</id2>
  </test>
</Document>
```

The output produced is:

```
<CONTENT>
   <TEST1>Hello!</TEST1>
   <TEST2>Hello again!</TEST2>
</CONTENT>
```

You could also try this, which is a little more verbose, but XSLT 1.0 compatible:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <CONTENT>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="/Document/test/id1" mode="rename">
        <xsl:with-param name="name" select="'TEST1'" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="/Document/test/id2" mode="rename">
        <xsl:with-param name="name" select="'TEST2'" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </CONTENT>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()" mode="rename">
    <xsl:param name="name" />
    <xsl:element name="{$name}">
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on the above sample XML, again the same output is produced.

Comment: Thanks a lot to you also this was where I was looking for. As I stated in the answer above. My original message has namespaces. When I uses your xlst2 solution in my solution then the xpath expression is printed not the content of the expression. Any Idea what I need to do to get the content?

Comment: I can't see why it would print out the XPath expressions unless you did something weird with it.  Could you provide an example above with your actual input XML, including the namespaces?